# How to troubleshoot hung docker container

Tags: docker

I have nodejs (5.3.0) application build with Ubuntu 8 Container image.  We run this container on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS server with Docker 17.09.0-ce.

In random time our application stop responding, we need to stop and start the container to restore the service.

Docker log and server logs didn’t have much information, what other details I can collect to debug this issue?

Thanks

SR

Comment: did you tried - docker-compose logs?

Comment: I  simple start container with `docker run`. docker-compose is not used.

Comment: If container's logs don't show anything interesting, maybe try logging more inside your app, maybe there's something in `js` that breaks it?

Comment: @trust512 it looks like application issue, what kind of data I can collect from application side.

Comment: node apps often got my containers hanging because of some of mine implementation flaws. Try putting prints/logs in many places inside your app and look where it hangs. Attach to the app while it boots up like `docker run -it ... ` to see if it doesn't behave inappropriately

Comment: Thanks for the direction, we will try this